# Nodejs Error: Cannot find module .. in ec2

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, amazon-ec2

My project tree is look like following:

`models/userStore.js`

`index.js`

I am exporting user information in index.js by using following command.
`const UserStore = require('./models/UserStore');`

It is working fine in my local machine. When i upload in ec2 , i am getting following error.

```
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../models/UserStore'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/test/dist/index.js:13:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:447:10)
```

index.js

```
 'use strict';

const Hapi = require('hapi');
const HapiSwagger = require('hapi-swagger');
const server = new Hapi.Server();
const Joi = require('joi');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const db = require('./db');
const UserStore = require('./models/UserStore');
UserStore.initialize();
const user = UserStore.users; 

server.connection({port: 3000});
server.register(require('./plugins/plugins.js'));

server.register([
    {
        'register': HapiSwagger    
    }
    ], (err) => {
        server.start( (err) => {
           if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log('Server running at:' + server.info.uri);
            }
        });
    });


var validate = function (request, decodedToken, callback) {
    var user = UserStore.users[decodedToken.email];
    if (!user) {
      return callback(null, false);
    }
    return callback(null, true, user);
};

server.register(require('hapi-auth-jwt'), function () {
  server.auth.strategy('token', 'jwt', { key: privateKey,
                                         validateFunc: validate,
                                         verifyOptions: { algorithms: [ 'HS256' ] }
                                       });
    server.route(require('./routes/endpoints/routes.js'));
});
```

Comment: Add `console.log(process.env)` in the beginning of `index.js` to test a `NODE_PATH` value.

Comment: Add full stack of the exception, pls. Not only `module.js:341 throw err; ^`

Comment: added full exception.

Comment: Thx, add `console.log(process.env)`, pls.

Comment: And post full `index.js` file too.

Comment: Perhaps the copy of index.js on EC2 is not updated somehow. The reason I think this is the case is that your provided index.js does not contain `..` anywhere and the line number from the stack trace does not match what is shown in your provided index.js.

Comment: @LutforRahman you can use lower-case and dashed file names to avoid this in future: `my-module-name.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The problem was my file name was(userStore) and when i exported i used (UserStore). As mac is case insensitive, it is running fine locally. As linux file system is case sensitive it throws that error.

more details: [Can I force node.js require to be case sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13617863/can-i-force-node-js-require-to-be-case-sensitive)

Comment: had the exact same problem! Luckily I found this thread